# Unable to execute JS call: _fbBatchedBridge is undefined

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run a React Native project ***on my device*** and I'm getting the following error

`Unable to execute JS call: _fbBatchedBridge is undefined`

I have upgraded to the latest version of React Native (0.43). I know there are a bunch of issues out there for this going all the way back to React Native 0.20 but a lot of them seem to have to do w/ people running their project via the simulator.

Anyone have any idea how I can get rid of this error? Again trying to run on an actual device w/ latest version of React Native (0.43)

Thanks!